# Asignar evento de teclado a una ventana en Java

Tags: java, java-swing, eventos, teclado

Hola estoy haciendo un monitor de cocina, muestra las ordenes que hay en la base de datos, pero quiero asignar una tecla F10 para entrar a la ventana de configuración. Pero si el foco esta en algún otro elemento no toma la acción. Hay alguna manera de ejecutar la acción sin que tenga que estar el foco en un elemento especifico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código es lo que necesitas.

Lo que hace es agregar un oyente global para los eventos de teclado (solo funciona para aplicaciones AWT/SWING). Puede ver más detalles del método utilizado [aquí](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#addAWTEventListener(java.awt.event.AWTEventListener,%20long)).

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
                // Como se usa la máscara AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK nunca va a fallar 
                KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) event;

                // es true cuando se ha soltado la tecla
                if (keyEvent.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                    // Aquí pones tu lógica
                    System.out.println("F10 " + (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F10));
                }
            }
    }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);// Esto indica que se escucharan solo los eventos de teclado
```

El código anterior debes ejecutarlo en cuanto inicies tu aplicación, no necesariamente en la ventana en cuestión. Pero debes tener en cuenta de que al agregar el oyente de manera global, dicha acción (la de la tecla F10) se podrá llevar a cabo en cualquier lugar de tu aplicación.

Si quieres evitar esto, para solo hacer que se ejecute mientras tu ventana esté activa, visible, o cualquier otro estado, debes agregar el oyente cuando muestras la ventana (o cuando quieras) y luego cuando ya no quieras escuchar el evento del F10 eliminarlo.

```
    AWTEventListener f10Listener = new AWTEventListener() {
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            // Como se usa la máscara AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK nunca va a fallar 
            KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) event;

            // es true cuando se ha soltado la tecla
            if (keyEvent.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED) {
                // Aquí pones tu lógica
                System.out.println("F10 " + (keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F10));
            }
        }
    };

    // Agrego el listener (lo agregas cuando lo necesites)
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(f10Listener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);

    // Elimino el listener (lo eliminas cuando ya no lo necesites)
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(f10Listener);
```

Comment: perfecto es justo lo que buscaba, funciono perfectamente, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Un placer ayudarte. Saludos!